# requests.get() doesn't return the correct html code of the web page

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to write a script in Python using requests and BeautifulSoup modules that would accept a domain name as input and print out the amount of results (e.g. "About 292 results").
Here is a part of my code:

```
def get_pages(domain):
    param = {'q' : "site:%s" %(domain)}
    url = "https://www.google.com/search"
    r = requests.get(url, params = param)
    h = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(h.prettify())
```

The problem is that the output html code doesn't contain all the information that I need. However, when I type the exact same url in my browser, the browser page has it. What is the reason that the requests.get() function doesn't return all the information that the web-page actually contains? Is there a way to solve this problem? Is there any other way to get the amount of result pages that Google shows? P.S. I apoligize for  my imperfect English as it is not my native language.

Comment: Actual webpages run javascript in the browser and show you results of that - it won't be contained in the simple html scrape of the website.  Using selenium and driving a Chrome browser to access the page can be a method to access this info.

Comment: JavaScript. Probably

Comment: You should probably use the official search API for stuff like this.

Comment: The official search API mentioned by @JohnnyWezel : https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the same information when searching manually and using `requests` is that in the latter case the page you are requesting knows that it is a machine sending the request. You can probably solve this by looking into using a so called headless driver. [This post](https://medium.com/@pyzzled/running-headless-chrome-with-selenium-in-python-3f42d1f5ff1d) goes through a simple example that seems a lot like what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the web site just checks the User-Agent header attribute you can just copy this attribute from your browser and add it to the header parameter in requests as follows :

```
requests.get(url="http://example.com",headers={"User-Agent": "Your browser user agent here","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q="})
```